# How to indent text within captionof?

Tags: captions, indentation

Does someone know how to indent the text within captionof?  I have a long caption that I want to make two paragraphs out of but indent does not seem to work.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

% make demo figure
\makeatletter
  \AtBeginDocument{%
    \def\Ginclude@graphics#1{%
      \begingroup\fboxsep=-\fboxrule
      \fbox{\rule{\@ifundefined{Gin@@ewidth}{150pt}{\Gin@@ewidth}}{0pt}%
        \rule{0pt}{\@ifundefined{Gin@@eheight}{100pt}{\Gin@@eheight}}}\endgroup}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}[c]{\linewidth}
\centering
\includegraphics{}
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{Title} \newline
\indent Paragraph 1 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text \newline
\indent Paragraph 2 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text}
\label{fig:angio}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I wouldn't use `\newline` (which doesn't start a new paragraph) but `\par`, set `\captionsetup{parindent=\parindent}` and remove `\indent`. (One needs to specify a shorter version without paragraph breaks in the optional argument then in order to avoid errors…)

Comment: `\usepackage[parindent=\parindent]{caption}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of two things. First of all, the `minipage` nullifies the value of `\parindent`. Secondly, captions are also typically set in a way that avoid indentation. You can save the current `\parindent` and force your alignment manually:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\savedparindent}
% Save \parindent
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\savedparindent}{\parindent}}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=.5\linewidth]{example-image}
  \captionof{figure}[Title]{\textbf{Title} \newline
  \hspace*{\savedparindent}Paragraph 1 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text \newline
  \hspace*{\savedparindent}Paragraph 2 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text}
\end{minipage}

\end{document}
```

You can use the functionality of [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption) to store this yourself using the option `[parindent=\parindent]`. However, this requires you to specify each paragraph as a *paragraph* - leaving a blank line between them:

```
  \captionof{figure}[Title]{\textbf{Title}

  Paragraph 1 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text

  Paragraph 2 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of text}
```

Note that I've used an optional title `Title` to avoid complications with content in the LoF.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't use `\newline` (which doesn't start a new paragraph) but `\par` (or a blank line) for getting real paragraphs. Then I'd set `\captionsetup{parindent=\parindent}` and remove `\indent`. One needs to specify a shorter version without paragraph breaks in the optional argument then in order to avoid errors:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{parindent=\parindent}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
  \includegraphics{foo}
  \captionof{figure}[\textbf{Title}: shorter version]{\textbf{Title}\par
    Paragraph 1 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot
    of text lot of text lot of text \par
    Paragraph 2 is found here with a lot of text lot of text lot of text lot of
    text lot of text lot of text.}
\label{fig:angio}
\end{center}
```