# Indent in multiline caption

Tags: tables, captions, indentation

I am trying to replicate a caption like the one below.

Thus far I have made the following modifications:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{labelsep=newline, labelfont=bf, singlelinecheck=off, justification=justified}

\caption{Table title.\newline \indent Table subtitle.}
```

However `\indent` does not seem to work in caption, so how do I get a single line indented in my caption?

Thank you for your help.

[image: Exhibit 1a]

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/149822/197451

Comment: Thank you but I saw this before and it will cause the text to start after the table numbering and is not the solution in the picture and not what I am looking for.

Comment: Found a solution in a different existing post. Sorry for not doing better DD. For future reference: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/277340/how-to-indent-text-within-captionof